# how to activate linux virtualenv in windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, virtualenv

so i created a python project on my `linux (Ubuntu 19.10) Machine`. I deployed it to `Heorku server`. Now  i cloned the Heroku repository to my ``` windows Machine``(Windows 10)`. i want to use the ```virtualenv`which i was created Earlier on my`Linux Machine```. How do i do that ??

**My Project Structure**

[image]

Comment: You can't move python virtual from Linux to windows.
but you can use "pip freeze > requirements.txt" to record python package that u need.
then use "pip install -r requirements.txt" to install requirements.

Comment: do i need to make a new virtualenv ??

Comment: Yes, you can create a new virtualenv, and then install python packages

Comment: Does it answer your question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+move